# Failed: error processing document in mongoimport

Tags: mongodb, csv, mongoimport

I am getting the below error while reading a csv file:

Failed: error processing document #1: invalid character 'a' in literal new or null (expecting 'e' or 'u')

There are some blank fields, which I am suspecting needs to be presented as 'null' to be read properly. Am I correct here?

SAMPLE CSV:

name,year,battle_number,attacker_king,defender_king,attacker_1,attacker_2,attacker_3,attacker_4,defender_1,defender_2,defender_3,defender_4,attacker_outcome,battle_type,major_death,major_capture,attacker_size,defender_size,attacker_commander,defender_commander,summer,location,region,note

Battle of the Golden Tooth,298,1,Joffrey/Tommen Baratheon,Robb Stark,Lannister,,,,Tully,,,,win,pitched battle,1,0,15000,4000,Jaime Lannister,"Clement Piper, Vance",1,Golden Tooth,The Westerlands,

Battle at the Mummer's Ford,298,2,Joffrey/Tommen Baratheon,Robb Stark,Lannister,,,,Baratheon,,,,win,ambush,1,0,,120,Gregor Clegane,Beric Dondarrion,1,Mummer's Ford,The Riverlands,

Comment: I tried adding null in place of empty string, but it still gives the same error

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess you didn't specify the file type with `--type csv` so `mongoimport`assumes you import a JSON file by default

--> Try to import with `--type csv --headerline`

Comment: Thanks a lot. In AWS documentation, it missing the following 3 lines in CSV file import.
    --type=csv \
    --headerline \
    --ignoreBlanks \

After I added the following 3 lines to the code as following, the CSV file was imported successfully to AWS documentdb.

Answer (score 0):

In AWS documentation, it missing following 3 lines in CSV file import.

```
    --type=csv \
--headerline \
--ignoreBlanks \
```

After I added following 3 lines to the code as following, CSV file imported successfuly to AWS documentdb.

```
mongoimport --ssl \
--host="sample-cluster.node.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017" \
--collection=sample-collection \
--db=sample-database \
--type=csv \
--headerline \
--ignoreBlanks \
--file=<yourFile> \
--numInsertionWorkers 4 \
--username=sample-user \
--password=abc0123 \
--sslCAFile rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem
```